# Problems with arrays

Tags: unity, c#

I'm having a problem with the arrays that is in my code, I found the problem,but I don't know where or what lines to fix it. First, I'm setting variables and I dragged the gameobjects and buttons inside below arrays in the inspector

```
public GameObject[] expansion;
public Button[] panelButton;
public int isExpanded = 0;
```

Then I call the gameobjects inside the arrays using these function by button that I've created in the scene.

```
public void Expand()
{
    Debug.Log(isExpanded);
    while(isExpanded>0)
    {
        if(expansion[isExpanded] != null && panelButton[isExpanded] != null)
        {
            expansion[isExpanded].gameObject.SetActive(true);
            panelButton[isExpanded].gameObject.SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log(panelButton[isExpanded]);
            isExpanded++;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I also created this function to enable and disable the gameobjects inside the array using panelButton that is visible in the scene

```
public void SelectBase(GameObject selectBase)
{
    if(expansion[isExpanded] != null && panelButton[isExpanded] != null)
    {
        if(selectBase == expansion[isExpanded])
        {
            return;
        }
        if(expansion[isExpanded] != null)
        {
            expansion[isExpanded].gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
            expansion[isExpanded].gameObject.tag = "Base";
        }
        if(selectBase !=null)
        {
            selectBase.gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
            selectBase.gameObject.tag = "NewBase";
        }
        expansion[isExpanded] = selectBase;
    }
    return;
}
```

The problem is, when I click on the SelectBase function, it will affecting the isExpanded value thus messing up with the gameobject arrays. Can anyone possibly give me some insights? Thank you

Comment: This line `while(isExpanded>0)` seems pretty equivalent to `while(true)` since you're using `isExpanded` as an array element indicator, I'm assuming it's either zero or higher. With that in mind, if either `expansion[isExpanded]` or `panelButton[isExpanded]` is ever null, you're never getting out of that loop. Also, it could be helpful to include what happens when you try to run the code in its current state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and yes the isExpanded value is set to 1 in the inspector, since I set one of the expansion gameobject in the array will be visible in the scene when the game starts. When I run the scene, if I click, let say a button containing SelectBase(), it will work once, but after I click on the button containing Expand(), the panelButton will be visible, but not the expansion gameobject, and the SelectBase() will increase the inExpanded value too.

Comment: I take it your loop isn't in a coroutine, meaning it will freeze your game forever when it runs until it crashes due to an OutOfBoundsException, at which point Unity will disable the script and all your code will stop working.

Comment: I finally fixed the problem but I have a problem when the condition is met inside one of the functions. I already updated the code..

Comment: So you fixed the original problem, and updated it with a completely different problem?

Comment: Oops sorry, will post them as an answer then

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to fixed the arrays. I messed up with the `isExpanded` count by the way, and that's why the functions weren't working properly in the first place. I also removed the `while` loop.

```
void Expand()
{
    if(isExpanded<=2)
    {
        Debug.Log(isExpanded);
        isExpanded=isExpanded+1;
        expansion[isExpanded].gameObject.SetActive(true);
        panelButton[isExpanded].gameObject.SetActive(true);
        Debug.Log(panelButton[isExpanded]);
        Debug.Log(expansion[isExpanded]);
        Debug.Log(isExpanded);
    }
    else if(isExpanded>2)
    return;
    Debug.Log("all spawned");
}

void Remove()
{
    Debug.Log(isExpanded);
    if(isExpanded>0)
    {
        expansion[isExpanded].gameObject.SetActive(false);
        panelButton[isExpanded].gameObject.SetActive(false);
        isExpanded=isExpanded-1;
        Debug.Log(isExpanded);
    }
    else if(isExpanded==0)
    return;
    Debug.Log("done");
}
```

But I still have to deal with the `'IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.'` everytime I click the button that runs `Expand()`, and all the objects inside the array is visible though, while the new `Remove()` function that I've made is working properly.